# Question about Meissner Effect video

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, levitation, cryogenics

In this video, what material is on top of the superconductor disk that keeping it cold? Is it just a circular chunk of dry ice?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws6AAhTw7RA

I'm planning on recreating something similar to this. I wanted to know if having some dry ice on top of the superconductor disc will help keep it cool or will it warm up faster past the critical temperature?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to keep it cold, dry ice etc. It looks like it is wrapped in some tissue such that you can touch it without gloves. The isolation might keep it cold for a little longer, though. You can think about some cotton for a LN reservoir, but that increases the risk of injury in case of contact to skin.

Comment: Yeah, I plan on using plastic tweezers/tongs to manipulate the disk. The cotton to absorb some LN2 sounds like a good idea.